# How do you specify the revision in the path for a Dropbox API "download" request?

Tags: dropbox-api

The documentation for the Dropbox API download request, which I found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download) states the following:

> rev deprecated String(min_length=9, pattern="[0-9a-f]+")? Field is deprecated. Please specify revision in path instead. This field is optional.

However, I've been unable to find any documentation of what the `path` with a revision looks like.

Even the [Dropbox API Explorer for download](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_download) shows `rev` as a parameter for the API request.

Does anyone know how you actually construct a path for the download request, of the Dropbox API that contains the revision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'rev' parameter is deprecated in favor of supplying the rev value in the 'path' parameter instead, as you pointed out. [The 'path' parameter supports](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download):

> `path` `String(pattern="(/(.|[\r\n])*|id:.*)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)")`

Specifically, you would supply a value like `rev:abcd1234` where 'abcd1234' is the rev you want to download.

That would look like this in the API v2 Explorer, for example:
[image: Example of using the 'rev:' path format in the Dropbox API v2 Explorer]

Comment: Got it! I was confused. It thought that you were supposed somehow combine the revision and the path instead of just supplying the revision. Thanks for clearing this up.